# Disable or remove a specific inline style in joomla 3.3.6

Tags: css, joomla, fonts, styles, inline

I tried to change the fonts and styles in my joomla website, and to achieve this I installed the following plugin:

[image: plugin_screenshot]

Consequently the body font was changed, however the inline styles were not.

How can i disable or remove inline styles, like the following one?

```
<span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde';">Test</span>
```

I need a lot help :)

Comment: What plugin did you install?

Comment: a special plugin , very easy you can manege your fonts , please look this screen shot  to more about plugin http://w11i.imgup.net/webc89f.png

Comment: I have added the image and suggested a big edit for your question. Hopefully it will be approved soon and people will be able to help you better than me.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks on the image it appears to me that this plugin of yours uses CSS selectors to choose which elements it will affect.

Given that my [assumption](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc) is correct, if your `span` tag is not being affected its likely because there is a conflict in the CSS selection order.

My suggestion to fix your problem is to add a specific class to your `span` tag, like for example `<span class="myNewShinySpanTag">` and then add the line `span .myNewShinySpanTag` to the text box of your plugin.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

good way is find the inline css and remove it.

but if you can not find it you can write an high Priority css to disable this properties.

you should find an unique selector for this code:

```
span
{
    font-size:unset !important;
    font-family:unset !important;
}
```